# Uploaded Android APK marked as Android Auto when not set in manifest

Tags: android, android-auto

I've looked through my whole project directory, and for the life of me, I cannot find where it would think it is an Android Auto. Going through this page:

https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html#auto-metadata

Nowhere in my Android manifest, do I set an automotive.

Could a library add to the manifest to make it an Automotive app?
Are there other things in the manifest I can check?

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check in your res/xml file and see if you have any media or notification
under - *uses* element.

You can also check in your manifest file if you have added Car GMS package in the meta-data element.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
   android:resource="@xml/your_auto_xml_file" 
/>
```

If the library you are importing in happens to be from the merchant who builds up the customized DHU, then these lib can infuse those properties in your project. One easy way would be to remove the library and see if it resolves the issue.